# Uppercase 'P' appearing as a block

Tags: 10.10, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I've had this problem intermittently for a while. It seems to occur after the endless Ubuntu updates, then I fix it. Then it comes back again. Recently it effected several characters, now (as of last restart) it's only uppercase P from the 'Ubuntu' font that is effected.

Any ideas on solutions?

Bonus points for identifying the cause!

I've tried the standard `sudo fc-cache -fv` but no luck this time.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: If the corruption "comes and goes"; only on certain letters at certain sizes and certain times, then it's most likely a video *driver* issue (or even video *RAM* issue!) related to cacheing of the font bitmaps.  For efficiency reasons, the letters are not drawn from their vector outlines each time, but the results are simply cached once and then stamped out all over the screen.  If that bitmap area where the **P** is stored in rendered form gets corrupted, then it'll get copied all over the place. Please could you publish a screenshot for confirmation. Does Ctrl-Alt-F1, Ctrl-Alt-F8 fix it?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards